Test Class with Quiddity
I have a method that is called from a trigger, it is to allow operations only from invocable actions or a remote action and block all other enumerations of invocation.
How can you set the quiddity of a test to alternate through the paths of the methods being covered?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_enum_System_Quiddity.htm
Ie if execution is from a lightning UI context with SYNCHRONOUS, an error would be raised.

you'll need to wrap the method in a class that implements an interface - then two classes that implement that interface - one for prod, one for testmethods; the latter allows you to inject via the constructor different use cases.. Read up on Dependency injection

There are many different ways to address such scenarios, but fundamentally you need the production code, when invoked from unit tests, to not use the real Quiddity value but instead some artificially "injected" value.
If you have written code in a way that allows mocking (i.e. your logic is not in static methods and you use some dependency injection approach) it's simply a case of introducing some form of "Quiddity Accessor" interface, with an appropriate method, so all access to Quiddity is done through an implementation of that interface. The specific implementation used then depends on the code being run in production or through a unit test. This is my recommended approach, but there is a lot more setup needed (so I'm not showing it here).
If you have not written code that allows mocking (e.g. you use static methods everywhere) you can still take a similar approach. However, instead of using an interface for the "Quiddity Accessor", you'd write a class similar to the following:
public class QuiddityAccessor {
    public static System.Quiddity quiddity {
        get {
            if (quiddity == null) {
                quiddity = Request.getCurrent().getQuiddity();
            }

            return quiddity;
        }
        set {
            Assert.isTrue(Test.isRunningTest());
            
            quiddity = value;
        }
    }
}

All production code would get the current request's Quiddity simply be using QuiddityAccessor.quiddity instead of Request.getCurrent().getQuiddity().
When a unit test wants to call some production code that relies on Quiddity and needs to provide a specific Quiddity value, it would simply set the value via QuiddityAccessor.quiddity = Quiddity.QUEUEABLE, for example, then invoke the production code and assert the results.
